# Power BI/MS Fabric - One Hybrid table with multiple sources - KQL & BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, kql, real-time-data, microsoft-fabric

I have a requirement where data needs to be read in real time. I have two sources available for this data:

- A BigQuery table that is refreshed daily with data from yesterday.
- An API that can provide the data in real-time but is limited to 1 hour interval (Last 1 Hour)

I already built an Event Stream that has a Python notebook source that gets the data from the API. This Python code runs every 5 seconds and gets the data from the last 4 seconds. The event stream then pushes the data into a KQL database. This currently works great!

What I want to do now is the following: Import historical data until yesterday from Bigquery, and Direct Query today's data from the real time KQL database. I want to have both results under the same table in my Power BI dataset to combine them with dimentional data and create some sort of a centralized datamart for reporting purposes.

My question is the following: Is it possible to either:

- Use Hybrid Tables (Dataflows) to Incrementally Refresh my data from BigQuery until yesterday and the rest get it from KQL in Real-Time?
- Or combine/append the data from these both sources while keeping the mixed direct query/import aspect of it?

The first scenario would be preferably for maintainability reasons.

If neither one of these scenarios is possible, what architecture/tips would you recommend to both have real-time data from an API and historical data from BigQuery and be able to combine them into one table/dataflow to be used in a centralized dataset?

In advance, thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to implement this is to store all the data in KQL databsase and use [Incremental Refresh with a DirectQuery partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview).

So you would load the BigQuery data into KQL database, or into OneLake and access it in KQL through a [OneLake Shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/real-time-analytics/onelake-shortcuts?tabs=onelake-shortcut)

In either case you are storing the data in Fabric instead of importing it into Power BI.

It's also possible to have two separate tables; one imported from BigQuery using Incremental Refresh, and another using DirectQuery to KQL.  But in that case your visuals would have to reference one or the other.  You can create measures that aggregate over both tables, though.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You mean I would take the data from BQ only one time and put it in KQL. Keep my event stream running for newer data, and create a simple dataflow that would have only one source which KQL in this case, with the "Real Time"/Direct Query option enabled. Is this right? I was thinking about a more "fun" solution but that would surely work. However I think Hybrid Table from multiple sources can be a good idea for PBI for this kind of scenarios. 

Follow-up question, do you have any idea how to enable the direct query option on a Dataflow directly online?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the Dataflow.  But I would steer clear of the Gen 1 Dataflows, if you can use OneLake or KQL instead.

Comment: The issue is that Incremental refresh is currently not possible in Gen2. My idea was to build data objects as dataflows that would separately and incrementally refresh and then call them into a centralized dataset that would be used as a "datamart". These dataflows can eventually be instantiated/Direct Queried for other purposes to provide a coherent/accurate data across usage. That's the idea behind using the dataflows.

Comment: So don't use Dataflows _at all_.  Either use Incremental Refresh with a Dataset, or load the data into OneLake using Pipelines, or Spark notebooks.

Comment: That takes out the "modular" aspect of things. You cannot instantiate the data objects (i.e Dataflows) separately. You have to either connect to all the dataflow or none. Is that not a possibility?

Comment: You have 4 choices for where how to store the data.  1) Dataflows Gen 1, 2) Datasets, 3) OneLake Delta Tables, 4) KQL Database.    The most "modular and flexible" of these is OneLake.  The best for fast-moving Real-Time data is KQL Database.